# Propane Engine Life

Tags: propane

It is commonly said that engines running propane, vs gasoline, last longer.

Taking out the factors such as application, I am inclined to think this is because upon cold start, the propane engine does not require a rich fuel mixture.  The rich mixture might result in condensation on cylinder walls in a gasoline engine. And in a diesel engine, fuel may be sprayed and may collect on the cylinder wall prior to engine start.  But in a propane engine, the vapors, at least in temperatures above arctic temperatures, are unlikely to condense on the cylinder walls.  Without the washing of the cylinder walls, there is less start-up wear.

My assumption is that this is the primary reason for longer life with propane as the primary fuel.

My question is: Is there research to back this up (or refute it)? Of course, some cites would increase credibility of any answer.

Comment: What have you found so far? So we don’t waste time finding stuff you already have...

Comment: Nothing. That is why I am asking.  I have not done a peer reviewed literature search, which is a gold standard.  However there are probably people who have good subject matter understanding, which is why I ask.  The cold start theory I floated, has always been my assumption, but I don't know for certain.  There are other theories, which I did not mention, such as the "clean fuel" theory, which I discounted.  The cold start theory interlaces with longevity in diesel engines, including frequent cold start applications.

Comment: Here is a theory : people running propane tend to treat the car with more care and don't accelerate as hard so improving engine life...

Comment: I think you'll find the longevity in diesel engines is no more, due to expensive fragile injectors, failing turbochargers, clogging EGRs, dual mass flywheels and exhaust gas treatment technology like diesel particulate filters and selective catalytic reduction. In contrast, the longevity of naturally aspirated gasoline engines has increased due to longer-lasting ignition system components and none of that high-tech that is required for diesels. As for propane, I'd be interested to see an answer to this question.

Comment: Wikipedia seems to agree with you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_natural_gas says "Increased life of lubricating oils, as CNG does not contaminate and dilute the crankcase oil."

Comment: To clarify, the contrast is with gasoline Otto cycle engines, not diesels.  And the applications are broad, to include fork trucks, mowers, stationary power plants, and, yes, automobiles or UTEs.

Comment: Primary reason is it is a much cleaner and efficient fuel, already in gaseous form. Gasoline is inherently dirty and has to go from a liquid state to a gas in the cylinder prior to combustion, any gas not in a gas state will not burn correctly or at all and leaves carbon and raw fuel in the cylinder which some of it makes its way into the oil system.

Comment: @Moab - I don't think it's more efficient, but you are absolutely right about cleanliness. What I'm cluing as "efficient" is content for content, what has more energy? If you are considering efficient to indicate how well (or completely) it burns, I'd give you that.

Comment: @Moab - [This will explain what I am talking about](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/energy-content-d_868.html). Gasoline has 124,000btu per gallon, where propane only carries 91,330btu. That's more than a third again the energy from propane to gasoline.

Comment: That's my point it is more efficient due to the fact there is far much less waste compared to gasoline.

Comment: Or less efficient as you need more to achieve same power...